# apply subset function to columns using other dataset with min/max values

Tags: r, subset, apply, tidyr

I am trying to apply subset function to each column with min and max values from another dataset.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
df <- mtcars
```

Min/max limits of the two columns:

```
dfLimits <- data.frame(Names = c("hp","wt"), Min = c(160,1.6), 
                       Max = c(220,NA),stringsAsFactors = F)`

Names   Min  Max
 hp     160   220
 wt     1.6   NA
```

trying to achieve the result of the following function using `apply` function since in my case I have many columns that I need to match between two datasets and set the limits.

```
df %>%  subset(hp < 220 & hp > 160 & wt > 1.6)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but we can create an expression dynamically and evaluate using `eval(parse())`. We replace `NA` values to `Inf`/`-Inf` in `Max`/`Min` respectively.

```
dfLimits$Max[is.na(dfLimits$Max)] <- Inf
dfLimits$Min[is.na(dfLimits$Min)] <- -Inf


subset(df, eval(parse(text = paste(dfLimits$Names, ">", dfLimits$Min, "&",
                      dfLimits$Names, "<", dfLimits$Max, collapse = " & "))))


#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

where the output of `paste` is :

```
paste(dfLimits$Names, ">", dfLimits$Min, "&", 
      dfLimits$Names, "<", dfLimits$Max, collapse = " & ")

#[1] "hp > 160 & hp < 220 & wt > 1.6 & wt < Inf"
```

---

If interested in `dplyr` solution we can use the same `paste` expression in `filter` with `parse_expr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df %>%
  filter(eval(parse_expr(paste(dfLimits$Names, ">", dfLimits$Min, "&",
              dfLimits$Names, "<", dfLimits$Max, collapse = " & "))))
```

Comment: thanks, very nice approach. in my case, column names start with numbers like `1_wt` and `2_hp` and cannot parse for that reason, do you know any way around this?

Comment: I am not completely sure about how your data is structured but you could try to get the data in long format using `pivot_longer`, use `separate` on `_` so that `1` and `wt` are into different columns and then use the above approach.